# On ajax call failed, wait for the next done of same call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do some actions inside my done method. this works fine as long as I'm authorized.

When I'm unauthorized, and get a 401 response from the server, I want to refresh my token and redo the action. I can do this now, but the console doesn't show `data`. How do i make the console show the message when the done function of my second call is available.

```
1  loadNotesByPageIdCall(documentUrl, pageId).done(function (data) {
2      console.log(data);
3  }
4
5  function loadNotesByPageIdCall(documentUrl, pageId) {
6      var result = $.ajax({
7         type: "GET",
8         url: "/Note/GetNotesByInternalId",
9         headers: headers,
10        data: { documentUrl: documentUrl, pageInternalId: pageId }
11    });
12    result.fail(function (data) {
13        if (data.status == 401) {
14            var myAjax = this;
15            handle401().done(function(succes){
16                if(succes){
17                    myAjax.headers = headers;
18                    // Do same request again
19                    result = $.ajax(myAjax);
20                }
21            });
22        }
23    });
24    return result;
25 }
```

**How to use the data returned by the second ajax call from the fail?**(line 19)

Comment: Good idea those line numbers, too bad there isn't an option on stackoverflow that does that automatically for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this helps...

```
 function doneFunction(data){
     console.log(data);
 }
function loadNotesByPageIdCall(documentUrl, pageId) {
      var result = $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/Note/GetNotesByInternalId",
         headers: headers,
        data: { documentUrl: documentUrl, pageInternalId: pageId },
        success:function(data){
            doneFunction(data);
        }
    });
    result.fail(function (data) {
        if (data.status == 401) {
            var myAjax = this;
            handle401().done(function(succes){
                if(succes){
                    myAjax.headers = headers;
                    // Do same request again
                    result = $.ajax(myAjax);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to add my done actions in my call method. I seperated the calls from the rest of the logic.

Comment: what about a done function outside and a function call inside suceess od ajax? are you ok with that?